# Getting the error Cannot set properties of undefined in angular unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

while I am writing the unit test case for dropdown I am getting the error as
*TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ReferralCodes')*
**.spec.ts**

```
it("should update the action selecting a value from category drop down", () => {
    component.actionCodesLookupData.ReferralCodes =[
      {
      Name: "some data",
      Id: 3,
      ActionStatus: 126
    }
    ]
    component.setActionCodesList("Referral");
    expect(component.actionCodesList).toBe(component.actionCodesLookupData.ReferralCodes);
       });
```

**.component.ts**

```
 public setActionCodesList(actionType: any):void{
   this.actionCodesList = [];
 
    switch(actionType){
      case ActionRecordConstant.memberContact:
      this.actionCodesList = this.actionCodesLookupData.MemberContactCodes;
     break;
      case ActionRecordConstant.referral:
        this.actionCodesList= this.actionCodesLookupData.ReferralCodes;
      break;
//some code
```

In code it is not showing the errors but test is failing showing the error as:

*TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ReferralCodes')*

can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that `actionCodesLookupData` is undefined when you set it.

Try setting it to an empty object first.

```
it("should update the action selecting a value from category drop down", () => {
    // !! add this line   
    component.actionCodesLookupData = {};
 
    component.actionCodesLookupData.ReferralCodes =[
      {
      Name: "some data",
      Id: 3,
      ActionStatus: 126
    }
    ]
    component.setActionCodesList("Referral");
    
 expect(component.actionCodesList).toBe(component.actionCodesLookupData.ReferralCodes);
});
```

Comment: Thanks@Alif50, added the line but showing the error as "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ActionLookupData': PlanYears, MemberContactCodes, ReferralCodes, OtherActionCodes, and 3 more" could you please help me on this.

Comment: @developer1 apparently `component.actionCodesLookupData` is strongly typed as `ActionLookupData`. To get around the type enforcement, you can use an `as any` [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions): `component.actionCodesLookupData = {} as any;`.